# Designing for S3

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, appharbor

How should I design my ASP.NET MVC application and database to cater for serving static content from Amazon's S3?

Presently I have an `Images` table for uploaded images on my local server. Each image has an ID and a local path to serve it from, but I want to move my static content to the cloud.

- What do I need to store?
- How do I serve S3 content via ASP.NET MVC 3?
- Do I serve content via a cached web request, or directly from S3?

I've been running dedicated servers for a long time, but I'm still learning about best practices on the cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AM is correct.  If your images do not need to be secture you can just make your Bucket public and allow direct access from your application to the URL on S3.

However if you want to secure the files on S3 to authenticated user you can use URL signing and a timestamp described here http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html

So your URL will be something like

```
  photos/puppy.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82
    &Signature=rucSbH0yNEcP9oM2XNlouVI3BH4%3D
    &Expires=1175139620
```

Comment: Besides the S3 URL, what else do I need to store to manipulate the image via my ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: in the DB you just need to store the Bucket and Key.  You would have the Private and Public key stored in your web.config or similar place

Answer (score 1):

You can store the urls of those resources on S3 in your .net server and redirect requests to those urls. Just in the same way that you're currently storing the local path to images from the `Images` table.

Also when serving static images, you just need to use the S3 urls instead of urls from the .net server.

What you probably want to avoid is to have to load the file from S3 using your .net app and serve them as responses unless you really have a reason for doing so.